# c# code error:Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct,A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

Tags: c#

@Habib and Ron Beyer. I corrected it as

```
public PQueue() : base() { }
```

But there are some errors exist in the static void Main() method. The errors are:

```
static  void Main() // error:Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
{
    PQueue  erwait =new PQueue();//error: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
    pqItem[] erPatient =new pqItem[4];//error: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
    pqItem nextPatient;
    erPatient[0].name= "Joe Smith";//error:Identifier expected
    erPatient[0].priority=1;//error:Identifier expected
    erPatient[1].name= "Mary Brown";//error:Identifier expected
    erPatient[1].priority=0;//error:Identifier expected
    erPatient[2].name= "Sam Jones";
    erPatient[2].priority=3;
    for (int x=0;x<=erPatient.GetUpperbound(0);x++)
        erwait.Enqueue(erPatient[x]);//error: Expected class, delegate, enum,    interface, or struct
    nextPatient=erwait.Dequeue();
    Console.WriteLine(nextPatient.name);
}
```

2. List item

Comment: Your `Main` method should be inside some class... Also that is not the way to call base constructor `public PQueue  { base();}` it should be `public PQueue() : base(){}`

Comment: @Habib it should probably be `public PQueue() : base() { }`, the problem here is the missing `()` on the constructor so its important to have.

Comment: "Lots of errors" is not descriptive enough, can you provide the compilation errors?

Comment: Obvious errors: items. GetUpperbouond(0) should read "items.GetUpperBound(0)", GetUpperbound should read "GetUpperBound"

Comment: It's from the book "Data Structures and Algorithms Using C#", which mentions at the latter code listing (`static void Main()`): _"The following code demonstrates a simple use of the PQueue class"_. It doesn't say "copy this and it runs". It's trying to explain concepts, not presenting runnable code. It is also a really crappy book that's full of errors, [read the reviews](http://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Using-C/dp/0521670152). I'd suggest looking for a more decent book, aimed specifically at beginners.

Comment: @RonBeyer, yes, for constructor it should be. I focused more on the `base` keyword rather than missing `()`.

Comment: *"Data Structures and Algorithms Using C#"* Is probably **not** the book you should be learning C# with. I would pick something like Head First C# or some other beginner level book. Starting with a data structures and algorithms book is like learning how to be a mechanic by taking apart a Ferrari, start with a Willys Jeep, you'll learn more fundamentals that way.

Comment: Thank You Ron. I read one book "sam's teach yourself c# language in 21days". But I didn't  compile  programs. Do you know some books that provide exampled programs?

Comment: @ Teagan42: Thanks. The errors are: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct; Identifier expected; Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected.

Comment: @Simona in regards to the "end-of-file expected" error, I noticed in the full code you posted yesterday it looked like there was an extra `}` at the end of it. Make sure all your parenthesis & braces line up with one another.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the constructor is poorly formatted:

```
public class PQueue : Queue
{
    public PQueue
    { base();}

    //Other code here
}
```

You should take care to learn how to create constructors properly, the way to call the base is:

```
public class PQueue : Queue
{
    public PQueue() : base()
    {

    }

    //Other code here
}
```

Also, take care in formatting your code. A lot of your problems can be avoided by properly formatted code, it will help point out where your problems are a lot faster. Read a code-formatting style guide for C# and make a habit of it.

There are also a lot of spelling and capitalization mistakes, for example:

```
GetUpperbouond(0)
```

Should be

```
GetUpperBound(0)
```

The golden rule to debugging is to fix the first error first, recompile and repeat.